# How to use the Glimpse client viewer but NOT the server implementation

Tags: javascript, javascript-framework, glimpse

I would like to use the [Glimpse client viewer](http://getglimpse.com/About/Details) in a web application in order to render some JSON.  I am unable to use the Glimpse server implementation on the site in question.  However, I can implement my own IHttpHandler to render the information using the Glimpse JSON format.

Has anyone done this and posted details on how to do it?  If not, can anyone tell me the steps required to get this up and running?  Alternatively, are there any other similar viewer frameworks out there?

*Note:  I am poking around [the source](https://github.com/Glimpse/Glimpse/) and have seen the client js etc.  I will continue down the source hacking route, but was hoping someone may have some shortcuts for me!*

Comment: Out of curiosity, why can't you use the server bits? This feedback might help us improve the product.

Comment: It is not really due to a problem with Glimpse.  I am providing an engine for use in a site and I want to add some Glimpse style output.  However, I do not want ANY of the built in plugins.  I just want to add my own sections for app specific data.  I could do this via Glimpse, but then I would have to add my engine to the site AND Glimpse (which is a bit messy).  Also, there is not .NET 4 on the web boxes.  Would love it if the bits to do this were cleanly separated (maybe they are?).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Nik said I would be interested in what you are trying to do. But in the mean time the best place to look is http://getglimpse.com/Protocol.

If you look on this page you will see that we have built a protocol tester. This allows you to put in any JSON and see the output.

If you want to do this yourself, have a look at http://getglimpse.com/Scripts/Protocol/LayoutExample.js and you will see how we do this without using the whole of Glimpse.

You will see that we are doing something like the following:

```
var data = { test : 'test', hello : 'hello' };
var html = $Glimpse.glimpseProcessor.build(data, 0, false)
$('.panel').html(html);
```

I know this isn't as nice as it could be but it wasn't designed with this in mind.

We are currently working on refactoring the client code to make this all better.

Comment: Up and running.  Thanks for the info.

Comment: both links are dead

Answer (score 1):

We haven't really documented all of this yet.

Your best bet is to look at first glimpse javascript file that gets rendered to a page - it is the data file.  If you can output data in that format, which is basically just one object of key value pairs, then the client will pick up the data and render it.

You might also want to look at the Glimpse.PHP implementation, since they'vve had to do the same thing you are.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Will give the PHP project a look too.  Had to give anthonyv the answer for his link LayoutExample.js